# How to depict REQUIRED elements in Biztalk Schema

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I am stuck trying to find a way to specify REQUIRED fields in my Biztalk schema files. Anyone have an answer for this? I tried to use the USE=REQUIRED attribute/value but that was rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use="required" is only used for XML attributes. For XML elements you need to set minOcurrs=1 instead. However, remember that BizTalk doesn't do XML schema validation by default, that's something you need to explicitly enable and does come with a performance cost.